# Changing Variables in Subscribe won't show up in data binding

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I have the 2 variables `currentPathEmpty` and `currentPathFill`. Both are strings.

I'm subscribing to a BehaviorSubject. I get notified once the subject changes and it prints the correct values in the console. As it should.

```
ngOnInit() {
    // Irrelevant to this quesiton
    this.exercise = this.workoutService.workout.exercises[this.index];

    this.currentPathEmpty = this.arrowUpPathEmptly;
    this.currentPathFill = this.arrowUpPathFill;

    this.workoutService.player.exerciseStateSubject.subscribe((state) => {
      if (state === 'Rest') {

      } else if (state === 'Positive') {
        this.currentPathEmpty = this.arrowUpPathEmptly;
        this.currentPathFill = this.arrowUpPathFill;
     } else if (state === 'Hold') {
        this.currentPathEmpty = this.rectPathEmpty;
        this.currentPathFill = this.rectPathFill;
      } else if (state === 'Negative') {
        this.currentPathEmpty = this.arrowDownPathEmpty;
        this.currentPathFill = this.arrowDownPathFill;
      }
      console.log(this.currentPathFill);
    });
}
```

However when I do this in my html:

`<h1>{{currentPathFill}}</h1>`

The value won't show up and chance on a subject change. What the problem here? Why will it print out the right values on the console but I can't data bind to it?

Comment: It's probably to do with the context of `this`, however the code you've shown wouldn't cause that. Can you please show the rest of that function (i.e. the function that code is inside)? And also maybe the code that calls that function

Comment: @user184994 sure, I put the function in the post. I just call it inside the ngOnInit() function without much else in it...

Comment: Hmmm.... Are you able to create a Stackblitz that reproduces the issue?

Comment: @Jonas, would it be possible for you to replicate this on a Minimal Sample StackBlitz demo?

Comment: Could you put the code of the service? where the BehaviorSubject is

Comment: I tired reproducing the problem in a stackblitz but can't seem to reproduce it... I also can't post the class where I create the BehaviourSubject because its too big...

Comment: Give a link to the stackblitz that you have so far.

Comment: @dmcgrandle https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mvsljs

Comment: After every line where `currentPathFill` is modified in code, add `console.log("currentPathFill", this.currentPathFill);`. That may help you to find the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Add `let self = this;`

```
 ngOnInit() {

     // Irrelevant to this quesiton
    this.exercise = this.workoutService.workout.exercises[this.index];
    this.currentPathEmpty = this.arrowUpPathEmptly;
    this.currentPathFill = this.arrowUpPathFill;

   let self = this;
try {
    this.workoutService.player.exerciseStateSubject.subscribe(
    function (state) {
    self.callMe(state);  <--- call a method
    },
    error => console.log('Getting Error :: ' + JSON.stringify(error)));
     } 
    catch (e) { console.error('Error :: ' + JSON.stringify(e)); }


     callMe(state){
     if (state === 'Rest') {

          } else if (state === 'Positive') {
            this.currentPathEmpty = this.arrowUpPathEmptly;
            this.currentPathFill = this.arrowUpPathFill;
         } else if (state === 'Hold') {
            this.currentPathEmpty = this.rectPathEmpty;
            this.currentPathFill = this.rectPathFill;
          } else if (state === 'Negative') {
            this.currentPathEmpty = this.arrowDownPathEmpty;
            this.currentPathFill = this.arrowDownPathFill;
          }
          console.log(this.currentPathFill);
        }


<h1 *ngIf="currentPathFill">{{currentPathFill}}</h1>
```

Comment: Tried it but still the same problem. Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 0):

OK the problem is that these two variable's

```
this.arrowUpPathEmptly
this.arrowUpPathFill;
```

values are binding after the OnInit()
check the console for order of the logs